# Filtra en tabla con #footable o javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables, html-tabla, filtro

Amigos que tal, estoy realizando un reporte en un inicio me carga todos los datos, pero después quiero filtra por tes meneras NOMBRE, ESTADO Y TIPO y en `nombre` que filtre a partir de 3 caracteres.

Por ejemplo que en un inicio puede buscar escribiendo el `nombre` , pero puede ir reduciendo el filtro con los `<select>`o viseversa.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>FooTable - A jQuery Responsive Table</title>
</head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div class= "container">
<div class="col-lg-10">
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-2 mb-2">
                    <input type="text" name="buscar" id="foo_filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar nombre"/>
                    <select name="estado_pago" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option> ---Seleccionar Estado---</option>
                      <option value="1">Sin pagar</option>
                      <option value="2">Pagado</option>
                      <option value="2">Cancelado</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="tipo_pago" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option> ---Seleccionar Tipo---</option>
                      <option value="1">Recurrente</option>
                      <option value="2">Puntual</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">nombres</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">1</th>
      <th scope="col">ABEL GOMEZ TUANAMA                                </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">2</th>
      <th scope="col">ACENCIO ALEGRIA GONZALES                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">3</th>
      <th scope="col">ADALBERTO SALDAÑA GONZALES                       </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">4</th>
      <th scope="col">JAIR FASABI SAJAMI                                </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">5</th>
      <th scope="col">CARMEN ROSA GONZALES                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">6</th>
      <th scope="col">DORIS DORITA FASABI DAVILA                        </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">7</th>
      <th scope="col">MARINA LLULIANA FASABI TUANAMA                    </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">8</th>
      <th scope="col">MARLON TUANAMA SATALAYA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">9</th>
      <th scope="col">LIX CACHIQUE TUANAMA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">10</th>
      <th scope="col">SILVIA HIDALGO RENGIFO                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">11</th>
      <th scope="col">SEGUNDO LEONARDO TUANAMA ISUIZA                   </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">12</th>
      <th scope="col">MILGUER ISUIZA SALAS                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">13</th>
      <th scope="col">ADRIAN ISUIZA USHIÑAHUA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">14</th>
      <th scope="col">ARTEMIDORO TUANAMA TUANAMA                        </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">15</th>
      <th scope="col">GILMEY RUIZ RAMIREZ                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">16</th>
      <th scope="col">MONICA TUANAMA VASQUEZ                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">17</th>
      <th scope="col">ELSA ISUIZA ISUIZA                                </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">18</th>
      <th scope="col">FABER RENGIFO ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">19</th>
      <th scope="col">FARAON GONZALEZ SALDAÑA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">20</th>
      <th scope="col">FELIPE RUIZ SOLSOL                                </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">21</th>
      <th scope="col">GEORGIO CUMAPA ISUIZA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">22</th>
      <th scope="col">GUSTAVO APUELA ISUIZA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">23</th>
      <th scope="col">HORACIO RENGIFO VASQUEZ                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">24</th>
      <th scope="col">HORACIO  TUANAMA ISUIZA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">25</th>
      <th scope="col">JOSE SANTOS CASTILLO AGREDA                       </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">26</th>
      <th scope="col">JAIMENA ISUIZA USHIÑAHUA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">27</th>
      <th scope="col">ISABEL RUIZ JESUS                                 </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">28</th>
      <th scope="col">LUIS VASQUEZ TUANAMA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">29</th>
      <th scope="col">MARDEN ISUIZA ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">30</th>
      <th scope="col">HODALIO  ISUIZA TAPULLIMA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">31</th>
      <th scope="col">TERCERO MIGUEL RENGIFO ISUIZA                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">32</th>
      <th scope="col">WENDY MOZOMBITE ISUIZA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">33</th>
      <th scope="col">CARTER RENGIFO ISUIZA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">34</th>
      <th scope="col">GREGORIO RUIZ ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">35</th>
      <th scope="col">POTENCIANO TUANAMA CABALLERO                      </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">36</th>
      <th scope="col">JOSE VASQUEZ DAVILA                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">37</th>
      <th scope="col">PEDRO SALAS TUANAMA                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">38</th>
      <th scope="col">JORGE RENGIFO VASQUEZ                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">39</th>
      <th scope="col">BONEY ISUIZA  USHIÑAHUA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">40</th>
      <th scope="col">ELAINE LUCIA SANCHEZ DE TELLO                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">41</th>
      <th scope="col">LARRY CRISTIAN AGUIRRE MURRIETA                   </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">42</th>
      <th scope="col">WASHINTONG RODRIGUEZ ORTIZ                        </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">43</th>
      <th scope="col">WIL DAVILA TUANAMA                                </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">44</th>
      <th scope="col">REINOL HIDALGO DAVILA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">45</th>
      <th scope="col">ROMAN TUANAMA ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">46</th>
      <th scope="col">ENITH SUAREZ AMASIFUEN                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">47</th>
      <th scope="col">DELFINA SHUÑA DE SALAS                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">48</th>
      <th scope="col">MIGUEL ISUIZA ONORVE                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">49</th>
      <th scope="col">SULEMA TAPULLIMA ISUIZA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">50</th>
      <th scope="col">ORLANDO MOZOMBITE TUANAMA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">51</th>
      <th scope="col">JOSE DAVILA TANANTA                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">52</th>
      <th scope="col">RAUL PISCO SALDAÑA                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">53</th>
      <th scope="col">SULMIRA INSAPILLO TUANAMA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">54</th>
      <th scope="col">MIULER JULIAN BARDALES SANGAMA                    </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">55</th>
      <th scope="col">LOLIN VASQUEZ SALDAÑA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">56</th>
      <th scope="col">RAFAEL TUANAMA ISUIZA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">57</th>
      <th scope="col">RICARTE FLORES PIZANGO                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">58</th>
      <th scope="col">CARMEN DAVILA SOLSOL                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">59</th>
      <th scope="col">PAOLI HIDALGO RENGIFO                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">60</th>
      <th scope="col">EUTIGIO DEL AGUILA TANANTA                        </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">61</th>
      <th scope="col">IGLESIA  EVANGELICA                               </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">62</th>
      <th scope="col">MARIA ANGELINA HERNANDEZ SERRANO                  </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">63</th>
      <th scope="col">LINCOL ISUIZA ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">64</th>
      <th scope="col">I.E. INICIAL No. 099 - LEDOY                      </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">65</th>
      <th scope="col">ELEONOR RUIZ TUANAMA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">66</th>
      <th scope="col">ANDERSON LUIS VASQUEZ SALDAÑA                    </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">67</th>
      <th scope="col">JUSTO EMILIO RODRIGUEZ DAVILA                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">68</th>
      <th scope="col">SANDRO RENGIFO ISUIZA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">69</th>
      <th scope="col">ALFREDO RENGIFO SINARAHUA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">70</th>
      <th scope="col">ADOLFINA VELA MURRIETA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">71</th>
      <th scope="col">HORACIO SALAS TUANAMA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">72</th>
      <th scope="col">ASOCIACION DE MOTOCARRISTAS AMOLEY EXPRESS        </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">73</th>
      <th scope="col">SOCORRO TUANAMA TUANAMA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">74</th>
      <th scope="col">NEURALUZ AGUIRRE SOLSOL                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">75</th>
      <th scope="col">GENITER TUANAMA ISUIZA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">76</th>
      <th scope="col">RAFAEL RODRIGUEZ ISUIZA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">77</th>
      <th scope="col">RUBEN MOZOMBITE ONORVE                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">78</th>
      <th scope="col">FLORENTINO TUANAMA ISUIZA                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">79</th>
      <th scope="col">GILBERTO TAPULLIMA TUANAMA                        </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">80</th>
      <th scope="col">MARIANA TUANAMA INSAPILLO                         </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">81</th>
      <th scope="col">SIMEON ONORVE CABALLERO                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">82</th>
      <th scope="col">MAGNO TUANAMA ISUIZA                              </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">83</th>
      <th scope="col">YULI TUANAMA INSAPILLO                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">84</th>
      <th scope="col">HEVER SEGUNDO CACHIQUE ISUIZA                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">85</th>
      <th scope="col">JHONY HIDALGO SINARAHUA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">86</th>
      <th scope="col">RANULFO TUANAMA ISUIZA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">87</th>
      <th scope="col">DELCIO  ISUIZA TAPULLIMA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">88</th>
      <th scope="col">ELVIRA MOZOMBITE TUANAMA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">89</th>
      <th scope="col">CYNTHIA  XIMENA VASQUEZ PISCO                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">90</th>
      <th scope="col">ALFREDO ISUIZA AMASIFUEN                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">91</th>
      <th scope="col">JOSE ISAUL TAPULLIMA TUANAMA                      </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">92</th>
      <th scope="col">WERVIL ISUIZA TUANAMA                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">93</th>
      <th scope="col">JERJES SAAVEDRA MURRIETA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">94</th>
      <th scope="col">JAVENCIO ISUIZA TUANAMA                           </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">95</th>
      <th scope="col">NILO RENGIFO RUIZ                                 </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">96</th>
      <th scope="col">JUANITO ISUIZA TAPULLIMA                          </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">97</th>
      <th scope="col">NOLAN ISUIZA TAPULLIMA                            </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Recurrente</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">98</th>
      <th scope="col">CELINDA SANCHEZ MENOR                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Pagado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">99</th>
      <th scope="col">ADELA MURRIETA FLORES                             </th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelado</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>
<tr>
      <th scope="col">100</th>
      <th scope="col">JUAN LORENZO ARIMUYA MACUYAMA                     </th>
      <th scope="col">Sin Pagar</th>
      <th scope="col">Puntual</th></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tus datos de donde vienen? porque lo que tendrias que hacer es filtar los datos que populan la tabla, pero por lo que veo esta todo a mano en la pagina.. no usasa ni jquery ni nada...

Comment: @gbianchi claro, pero solo en el ejemplo muestro pocos datos pero son mas y cuento con paginación y en este ejemplo no lo puse. como debería ser el javascript a usar?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo real de tu pagina. tenes los datos hardcodeados en la pagina? o vienen de un back? como se genera tu pagina?